# migrating site to new ip - some computers still see the old site

Tags: ip, bind, migration

I have moved the site domain.com from ip.1.1.1 to ip.2.2.2.  I have changed the A records in bind on the DNS.

My local DNS is set to google's (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4), so for me, the issue was resolved in less than an hour, and when I open my browser, it shows domain.com at ip.2.2.2.

The problem is, in many places, whose routers have a very long cache (or some other reason), they still see the old ip address.

My main question is:

What can we do on the site of the old ip address to cause the browser to redirect to the new website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options for what you can do on the old IP address to get users to the new site:

- If the problem is caching in the browser, send a TCP RST packet. That tends to trigger a new DNS resolution by the browser.
- Have the old IP run a (reverse) proxy to direct the requests to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you increase `serial` for that zone after making any changes, also if you provide *REAL* DNS record I can take a look at it, but without talking anything specifics it could be number of things: local browser cache, DNS caching.